# How can I limit the queue size in BFS search ~ Java

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

Here is my BFS search method :

```
   private void doBfs(HiRiQ node, ArrayList<HiRiQ> queue, ArrayList<HiRiQ> path, ArrayList<HiRiQ> visited) {


        while(!queue.isEmpty()){

          HiRiQ current = queue.remove(0);


          if(current.IsSolved()){
            current.print();
            System.out.println("Path found !");

            return;

          } else {

            if(current.getAllNextStates().isEmpty()){ return; } 

            else {


              if(queue.contains(current)){ continue; }

              else if (visited.contains(current)){ continue; }


              else{ queue.addAll(current.getAllNextStates()); } 



            } 
                visited.add(current);
          }
        }
      }
```

This algorithm supposedly starts from a peg-solitaire puzzle configuration, and checks all the neighbor configurations until it finds the solved configuration. It appears to work but for any configuration it takes a really LONG time to run and find the solution.

One way to optimize this search algorithm would be to limit the queue size because after a certain point I would just spend most of my time putting more nodes in the queue and very little time actually processing nodes. So at some point I should stop filling in the queue and just check whether I have a solution waiting in your queue.

How could I possibly achieve this ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use [iterative deepening depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search). It was designed when memory was a big deal and naive BFS based solutions of some graph problems could easily eat all available RAM. But it does what you want to reach, limits the queue size, guaranties to find shortest path solution and it's faster than BFS if the branching factor is high.

Another way to improve the performance of your solution would be finding a good heuristic for solving the puzzle. Once you have the heuristic that you can code, you can try your luck with [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)